# Compare dates with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have multiple dates fields in the subscribers list and I need to find which one is first in chronological order. How can I do that with AMPscript?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare them via the [DateDiff() function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/datediff/).

Sample:

DateDiff(@Date1, @Date2, D)

OUTPUT: This would give you the difference between date 1 and date 2 in days(D).  You can also do Years(Y), Months(M), Hours(H) and Minutes(MU).

You can then do an IF/THEN statement to designate your date order:

Example below:

```
%%[
SET @DATE1 = Dateinfo1
SET @DATE2 = Dateinfo2

SET @DateDiff = DateDiff(@Date1, @Date2, D)

IF @DateDiff > 1 THEN]%%  

  <p>@DATE2</p>
  <p>@DATE1</p>

%%[ELSE]%%

  <p>@DATE1</p>
  <p>@DATE2</p>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: yeah DateDiff() is the only thing I could find too. The problem is that I will have to go through multiple columns to compare the dates and then I will need to see which ones have negative numbers somehow and then identify the closest date. A bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

If you had 5 discrete date columns you can do it with a simple loop and conditional. Just build a simple rowset of the field names, get the value for each one and loop through to find the max value.

**Sending Data Extension:**

```
EmailAddress,DateField1,DateField2,DateField3,DateField4,DateField5
aspriggs@degdigital.com,2016-01-01,2016-09-15,2016-09-14,2016-09-11,2016-09-01
aspriggs@degdigital.com,2016-01-01,2016-09-15,2016-09-14,2016-09-11,2016-09-01
```

**Code:**

```
%%[

var @i, @max, @varNames, @varNameArr, @dateField, @dateFieldValue
set @varNames = "DateField1|DateField2|DateField3|DateField4|DateField5"
set @varNameArr = BuildRowsetFromString(@varNames,"|")
set @numVars = rowcount(@varNameArr)

set @max = dateparse("1900-01-01")

for @i = 1 to @numVars do

  set @dateField = Field(Row(@varNameArr, @i),1)
  set @dateFieldValue = AttributeValue(@dateField)
  outputline(concat("<br>",@dateField,": ",@dateFieldValue))

  if @dateFieldValue > @max then
    set @max = @dateFieldValue
  endif

next @i

outputline(concat("<br>max: ",@max))

]%%
```

**Output:**

```
DateField1: 1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM 
DateField2: 9/15/2016 12:00:00 AM 
DateField3: 9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM 
DateField4: 9/11/2016 12:00:00 AM 
DateField5: 9/1/2016 12:00:00 AM 
max: 9/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
```