# AMPscript to hide form after certain date

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm running into a roadblock with AMPScript on a cloudpage. I'm wanting a form to be present before a date occurs and then hiddden after that date.

In the iterations I've tried, I've only seemed to get a blank page appearing OR  I'm seeing the wrong if statement. Here's the most recent version of my code.

```
%%[ Set @month = DatePart(NOW(), 'month')
Set @day = DatePart(NOW(), 'day')

IF (@month <= 05 AND @day <= 02) THEN ]%%
form html
%%[ ELSE ]%%
This event is closed for registration
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: You can use DateDiff to compare closure date and NOW() check this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/138889/28187

Comment: Ok thank you that helps. So would it look something like this?

`%%[
set @currentTime  = Now()
set @currentTime =  format(@currentTime,"yyyyMMdd")

set @closingDate = '2023-05-02'

SET @DateDiff = DateDiff(@CurrentTime, @closingDate, D)

IF @DateDiff > 1 THEN]%%  

Form HTML 

%%[ELSE]%%

This event is closed for registration

%%[ENDIF]%%`

Comment: please see answer provided

Answer (score 1):

Example of [DateDiff()](https://ampscript.guide/datediff/), you don't need to format *NOW()*

```
%%[
VAR @dateClose
SET @dateClose = '2023-05-31'

IF DateDiff(NOW(),@dateClose, D) < 0 THEN
]%%  

  <!-- Form html here -->

%%[ELSE]%%

  <p>This event is closed for registration</p>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: take note that NOW() is in servertime which is CST, Indianapolis (UTC-6) timezone. So your local time (and potentially expected behavior) might be several hours offset; e.g. my own is currently UTC+2 (but only half year long, given daylight saving time).